# Count words (even multiples) in a text with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

I have to write a function that counts how many times a word (or a series of words) appears in a given text.

This is my function so far. What I noticed is that with a series of 3 words the functions works well, but not with 4 words and so on.

```
from nltk import ngrams

def function(text, word):
    for char in ".?!-":
      text = text.replace(char, ' ')

    n = len(word.split())
    countN = 0
    bigram_lower = text.lower()
    word_lower = word.lower()

    n_grams = ngrams(bigram_lower.split(), n)

    for gram in n_grams:
        for i in range (0, n):
            if gram[i] == word_lower.split()[i]: 
                countN = countN + 1

    print (countN)
```

Comment: what do you meen does not work with 4 words and so on? Do you get an error message? is the output not what you expected?

Comment: @BendikKnapstad Let's say word/phrase is "I like to swim" and in the text that phrase appears once. The function prints 4

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but can't you just use `str.count()`

Comment: @JammyDodger that would count "hello there" even if the text is "hello theree"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, please fix your indentation and don't use bigrams as a variable for ngrams as it's a bit confusing (Since you are not storing just bigrams in the bigrams variable). Secondly lets look at this part of your code -

```
for gram in bigrams:
    for i in range (0, n):
        if gram[i] == word_lower.split()[i]: 
            countN = countN + 1

print (countN)
```

Here you are increasing `countN` by one for each time a word in your ngram matches up instead of increasing it when the whole ngram matches up. You should instead only increase `countN` if all the words have matched up -

```
for gram in bigrams:
    if list(gram) == word_lower.split(): 
        countN = countN + 1

print (countN)
```

Comment: gram is a tuple while word_lower.split() is a list so that won't match.  May I suggest: `if list(gram) == word_lower.split()`

Comment: @Mrlaf i messed up just gonna edit it, forgot to change type and left the for loop in

Comment: @DarrylG Not working. With a phrase of 4 words I'm still getting 4 as result of the function

Comment: @Mrlaf did you remove the `for i` loop as well ? I forgot to remove it in my original answer. It needs to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

May be it was already done in [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-count-occurrences-of-each-word-in-given-text-file-using-dictionary/)

Is nltk mandatory?

```
# Open the file in read mode 
text = open("sample.txt", "r") 

# Create an empty dictionary 
d = dict() 

# Loop through each line of the file 
for line in text: 
    # Remove the leading spaces and newline character 
    line = line.strip() 

    # Convert the characters in line to  
    # lowercase to avoid case mismatch 
    line = line.lower() 

    # Split the line into words 
    words = line.split(" ") 

    # Iterate over each word in line 
    for word in words: 
        # Check if the word is already in dictionary 
        if word in d: 
            # Increment count of word by 1 
            d[word] = d[word] + 1
        else: 
            # Add the word to dictionary with count 1 
            d[word] = 1

# Print the contents of dictionary 
for key in list(d.keys()): 
    print(key, ":", d[key])
```

Comment: this only works for unigrams (or single words) it does not help give a distribution for bigrams or larger ngrams

Answer (score 0):

This shuld work for you:

```
def function(text, word):
    for char in ".?!-,":
        text = text.replace(char, ' ')
    n = len(word.split())
    countN = 0
    bigram_lower = text.lower()
    word_lower = tuple(word.lower().split())
    bigrams = nltk.ngrams(bigram_lower.split(), n)
    for gram in bigrams:
        if gram == word_lower: 
                countN += 1
    print (countN)
```

```
>>> tekst="this is the text i want to search, i want to search it for the words i want to search for, and it should count the occurances of the words i want to search for"
>>> function(tekst, "i want to search")
4

>>> function(tekst, "i want to search for")
2
```

Comment: have you run my code? I altered your code and i get the correct output